# How to turn potential loop query to set based?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have something like this currently -

```
declare @thisDate smalldatetime

create table #theseDates (thisDate smalldatetime)
insert into #theseDates(thisDate)
values ('11/1/2016', '5/1/2017', '9/30/2017)

create table #someData (productid int, productname varchar(32), productprice float, productsolddate smalldatetime)

declare date_cursor cursor for
select thisDate from #theseDates

open date_cursor
fetch next for date_cursor into @thisDate

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
   insert into #someData(soldid, productid, productname, productprice, productsolddate)
   select soldid, productid, productname, productprice, productsolddate
   from soldproducts
   where productsolddate between @thisDate and getdate()

   fetch next from date_cursor into @thisDate
end

close date_cursor
deallocate date_cursor
```

How do I change this from a cursor to a set-based solution? 
NOTE: added fetch line

Comment: you should explain what the cursor currently does..

Comment: Just taking the `MIN(thisDate)` should give you the correct data set. Unless I'm missing something. You're using a cursor to insert duplicate data, basically.

Comment: You aren't fetching the next date into the cursor, was this intentional? Seems like @WEI_DBA suggestion should work.

Comment: another `fetch next...` should be inside loop

Comment: @WEI_DBA - the fetch is added now.

Comment: @scsimon - the fetch is added now.

Comment: @Parfait  - the fetch is added now.

Comment: Looks like you want cross apply

Comment: @scsimon - well. never used that before. but ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a cursor to solve this OP. Use CROSS Join instead 
This way faster than Cursor. 

See below. 
FYI. the mydates table is just a random date example because I don't want type them

```
declare @myproducts table (prodid int, proddesc varchar(30), prodprice money, solddate date)

insert into @myproducts
values 
(1,'prod 1',1,dateadd(day,-1,getdate())),
(2,'prod 2',10,dateadd(day,-10,getdate())),
(3,'prod 3',100,dateadd(day,-5,getdate())),
(1,'prod 1',1.5,dateadd(day,-6,getdate())),
(2,'prod 2',8.99,dateadd(day,-20,getdate())),
(3,'prod 3',95,dateadd(day,-15,getdate())),
(1,'prod 1',0.89,dateadd(day,-2,getdate()))

select * from @myproducts


declare @mydates table (mydate date)

/* reporting datefrom */

insert into @mydates
values (dateadd(day,-11,getdate())),(dateadd(day,-20,getdate())),(dateadd(day,-3,getdate()))

select * from @mydates

/* apply cross join to distribute the datefrom but should only be to data where solddate is between datefrom and today */

-- insert statement to dump all qualified data or not
select p.*,d.mydate [DateFrom] from @myproducts p
cross join @mydates d
where solddate between mydate and cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: Aside: `GetDate()` is treated a bit oddly in queries. Each _instance_ will have a constant value within a query. For example `select GetDate() as D1, GetDate() as D2 from SomeTable` may return two different values for the two columns, but they will not vary from one row to the next. When using `GetDate()` in multiple statements, e.g. within a stored procedure, one may avoid interesting surprises by getting a single value and using it throughout, i.e. `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate();` and use `@Now` as needed.

Comment: Which getdate are you referring to?

Comment: For example, the `GetDate()` calls in `insert into @mydates
values (dateadd(day,-11,getdate())),(dateadd(day,-20,getdate())),(dateadd(day,-3,getdate()))` might return two different dates if the statement is executed near midnight. It doesn't make much difference for sample data in an example, but it could cause a rare problem in production code.

Comment: Jeepers... that is only an example coz i dont want to type dates. My goodness!

Comment: @maSTAShuFu - Thanks. From what I can tell, this does exactly what I needed it to do.